# Save Sql Recordset into the csv file with well formatted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to dump my sql query result into the text file. i have created the following query,

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(2048) 

SET @cmd = 'OSQL -Slocalhost ' 
            + ' -UCRN370 -PCRN370' 
            + ' -Q"SELECT TOP 5 GageId FROM EwQMS370..msgages"' 
            + ' -oc:\authors.csv' 

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, NO_OUTPUT
```

The above query created the CSV file authors.CSV. But the content of the file is not formatted properly. They showed some junk data.

I need to create a formatted csv file.

Comment: What does output look like? what is junk? what is "good"?

Comment: exactly - tell us **what** you got, and **what** you expected instead - we need to see that delta in order to be able to help...

Comment: It returned lots of small boxes and lines between actual data. Records also not displayed row by row [ie first column is in first line and the next is few rows after in csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with BCP, CLR, SSIS or DTS given your example BCP is likely the best fit.

```
BCP EwQMS370..msgages out c:\Authors.csv -c -t, -T –S<servername>
```

You can still run this through xp_cmdshell in the same way as you are in your example; only BCP will do the heavy lifting of the CSV formatting for you. [Booksonline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) will go through BCP in more detail. If you need to select less columns from your table create a view to restrict the data down.

Comment: Thanks. Its worked fine. How can i set first row as column name [header]?

Comment: This will probably help

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/brettk/archive/2005/04/13/4395.aspx